# Reqular expression: How can I capture this text as two match?

Tags: python, regex

Here is the text to extract.

```
A=1
>a=1

>b=2

>if a==b:
>   print "same"
>else: print "not same"

Z=1 
F=FUNCTION_Z(1234)

>x=1
>y=2

>z=1
```

I'm try to extract text like this as two match.

```
>a=1

>b=2

>if a==b:
>   print "same"
>else: print "not same"
```

and

```
>x=1
>y=2

>z=1
```

I tried `"(([\>].*?[\r\n])[\r\n]+)*"` but It didn't work.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex will do matching from the line which starts with `^` upto the line which don't starts with `>` (blank lines are excluded).

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '''A=1
>a=1

>b=2

>if a==b:
>   print "same"
>else: print "not same"

Z=1 
F=FUNCTION_Z(1234)

>x=1
>y=2

>z=1'''
>>> re.findall(r'(?m)^>(?:.*)(?:[\r\n]+>.*)*', s)
['>a=1\n\n>b=2\n\n>if a==b:\n>   print "same"\n>else: print "not same"', '>x=1\n>y=2\n\n>z=1']
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mF2vY7/3)

Comment: Your expression skips blank lines. I just copied yours and pasted into my source code. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that by myself.
My solution is "([>].*?[\r\n])[\r\n]*([>].*?[\r\n])*" .